# How to open atom html code on browser(chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, atom-editor

I'm having a lot of problems trying to run my code in Google chrome from atom text editor. I installed a package that said "open in browser" however it opens my media file causing an error. I did get the live preview but I would also like to see the results of my code on a regular browser.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you try the script package? Did it fix your problem?

Answer (score 6):

***> To open file normally using any browser***

- Navigate to Atom Text Editor Settings > ctrl + , > Install > open-in-browser >
  click Install
- Once Installed Navigate to file on left pane > Right Click >
  [image: screen capture of navigation]

***> To open file live and see changes as you edit using chrome browser***

- Navigate to Atom Text Editor Settings > ctrl + , > Install > atom-live-server
- Then create a file in your project folder with extension
  *.atom-live-server.json*
- In the folder you have created paste the details below

**For Chrome under OSX, the block you need is:**

```
// .atom-live-server.json
{
  "browser": "google chrome"
}
```

**For Chrome under Windows:**

```
// .atom-live-server.json

    {
      "browser": "chrome"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Atom package "script" at https://atom.io/packages/script to run HTML as well as many other languages by using the command `script:run`.

Answer (score 0):

right-click on the index.html file under the project tab, click on the 'Copy Full Path', then open chrome and paste that into the address bar at the top.